# Changing tfs credential

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I have a project in tfs.
I use visual studio 2013. 
I removed tfs credentials from Control Panel->User 
Accounts->Credential-> Manager Windows Credentials. After that i can't add new credentials, project still connects to server but i lost the mapping. When i try to map the project i receive a message "The path some my path is already mapped in workspace some workspace", but i not see this workspace in the project. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After remove tfs credentials from Windows Credentials. You also need to close and open Visual Studio 2013, then reconnected to TFS. If it still not work, try to [clear TFS and VS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/). Also try to clear IE cookies and stored password, more details please refer [this link](https://www.jayway.com/2012/12/17/changing-tfs-credentials-in-visual-studio-2012/).

For your situation, you can use [tf workspace /delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y901w7se.aspx) command to delete that workspace.

***List of all workspaces by the following commands:***

```
C:\YourWorkspaceFolder>tf workspaces /owner:*
```

***Delete the workspace with the following command:***

```
C:\YourWorkspaceFolder>tf workspace /delete /server:BUILDSERVER WORKSPACENAME;OWNERNAME
```

Moreover, you can aslo use [Team Foundation Sidekicks 2013](http://www.attrice.info/downloads/index.htm#tfssidekicks2010) which is free and provides a GUI for viewing and deleting TFS workspaces.

Comment: Thanks. It was helpful for me.

Comment: NP, if it works, could you mark it as an answer. Which will be more convenient for others who search in this site.